# Communication between Teams and Web Chat via Bot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

With `https://portal.azure.com` I managed to create a `QnA Bot`.

I also managed to send a message from the `Bot Framework Emulator` to `MS Teams` and the `Test Web Chat` of the bot. (Though it is very static and manually done as of now)

I get my `Token` from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`. With that `Token` I can send a message to `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/ConversationID/activities` (which is `Teams`) and I can send a message to `https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/conversations/ConversationID/activities` (which is the `Test Web Chat`).

Little bit offtopic: Since I'm new to Azure I wonder if everything done so far is fine or completly false?

Anyway...

My goal so far is that when writing a message in the `Test Web Chat` the message should also end up in `MS Teams`. Then from `Teams` I want to answer to the message like `@Bot This is my Answer`. This Answer in Teams should then also end up in the `Test Web Chat`. (So basically communication between `Teams` and `Web Chat`)

What would be the best approach to do this?

I was thinking of a backend in Azure but I don't know what would be possible to use and if it's even possible.

My idea was:

A message is sent `Web Chat`. In Code I would upload the `Web Chat Conversation` Information to `Azure`. Also in Teams there is now the same message that was written in `Web Chat`. The Conversation ID in `Teams` also needs to be uploaded now and the Conversation ID the `Web Chat` is sending to needs to be updated (this would be needed so there is no spamming of new threads/messages in `Teams` from one Conversation and all the messages from this `Web Chat` Conversation are now in one thread.) Now to answer in the Conversation of the `Web Chat` via `Teams` I would write and send the answer. Before the sending of the answer happens I would need the Conversation ID from the `Web Chat`. So the Bot would download the information from `Azure` so it knows where it has to sent the answer to.

Is this a good apporach or do you know better ones? Also what ressources in Azure could I use to achieve this?

Comment: Please start with [Proactive messaging for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) to create simple POC. Please let us know if you facing any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are thinking about this the right way. Basically you want to pair two conversation references - one in Teams and the other in Web Chat - together and then forward the messages between the two.

**BotFramework SDK v4 (C#)**

I would recommend creating two functions - `AddConversationReferenceAsync` and `GetConversationReferenceAsync`. In those functions, you should manage how you store, connect, and retrieve conversation references. You can check the channel Id - `activity.ChannelId` - to determine how you want to handle the reference. Then in `OnMessageActivityAsync` you can add and retrieve the corresponding conversation references to send a proactive message to the other channel.

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    AddConversationReferenceAsync(turnContext.Activity as Activity);
    var conversationReference = GetConversationReferenceAsync(turnContext.Activity as Activity);

    if (conversationReference != null) {
      await turnContext.Adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, (ITurnContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => {
        await context.SendActivityAsync(turnContext.Activity);
      }, cancellationToken);
    } else {
      await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("You are not connected to anyone at the moment");
    }
}
```

**Screen Capture**

[image]

I would recommend looking at the BotBuilder [Proactive Messaging](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) sample, and [@tompaana](https://github.com/tompaana/) built a [Hunan Handoff Bot](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample) sample that connects conversations in Teams and Slack that might be helpful.

Hope this helps!