# How to get message events published on a Web API endpoint and feed it to bot framework v4 (C#, .Net Core Bot)?

Tags: botframework

I am using a third party API to provide Agent Handover (human chat) capabilities to my v4 based bot. The API requires a call back hook/ endpoint where it can send the messages/events back from the agent, and I have to get messages from it and display to users. When ever a new chat session is established a new session id is generated. And thus Session Id is passed back in all messages and events. Essentially they are sending events as Fire&Forget with a retry on failure.

For now  I had implemented an eventstore (in Cosmos dB) to store events/messages and then poll Cosmos periodically display message back to user and mark them processed.

Is there any way to make it more real time or pub-sub kind of analogy?

I would like to know if some one have already implemented scenario like this. What should be the way to respond the incoming messages from agent to bot user.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a client using the [Direct Line API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to handle routing messages between the third party agent handover and the bot. Then in the bot you can pair the third party Direct Line conversation references with the user's conversation reference to forward the messages accordingly with proactive messages. For more details take a look at this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215563/communication-between-teams-and-web-chat-via-bot/57313761#57313761).

Hope this helps!